# Flutter - Provider

Tags: flutter, provider

I am trying to create following widget, in which pressing a button the user should be redirected to MainGameScreen().

```
Widget quitGame(BuildContext context) {
showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return Dialog(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        ),
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              padding:
                  EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 20),
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 45),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        offset: Offset(0, 10),
                        blurRadius: 10),
                  ]),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    "QUIT GAME",
                    textScaleFactor: 1,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 40, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 15,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "Are you sure you want to leave the game?",
                    textScaleFactor: 1,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                              primary: Color(0xFFec4688),
                            ),
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.of(context).pop();
                            },
                            child: Text("NO",
                                textScaleFactor: 1,
                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20))),
                      ),
                      Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                              primary: Color(0xFF1fd281),
                            ),
                            onPressed: () {
                              roundTimer.cancel();
                              Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => MainGameScreen(),
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                            child: Text("YES",
                                textScaleFactor: 1,
                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20))),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    });
}
```

But when I do this I get the following error:

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following ProviderNotFoundException was thrown building Builder:
Error: Could not find the correct Provider<AuthBloc> above this MainGameScreen Widget
```

Unfortunately I don't have good understanding of provider, so I would be grateful if someone could explain what is going wrong and how I can fix it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MainGameScreen Widget` must be a descendant of `Provider` Widget. But here, you used `MaterialPageRoute` to push a new route to your app, so `MainGameScreen` will be in a new seperated branch of the widget tree, it's only parent is the `Material App Widget`. So there is two solutions for this:

```
1. Place the ProviderWidget above the MaterialApp Widget. Ex:
      Provider<AuthBloc>(   
        create: (context) => AuthBloc(),  
        dispose: (context, bloc) => bloc.dispose(), // remove it if there is no dispose method in your BLoC
        child: MaterialApp(),  
        ),



2. A trick, which is very useful but really hard to test and manage: Add a `static` method which look like this :
    
        class MainGameScreen extends StatefulWidget {
                  static Widget create(BuildContext context) {
                    return Provider<AuthBloc>(
                      create: (_) => AuthBloc(),
                      child: MainGameScreen(),
                    );
                  }
```

and when we use `MaterialPageRoute` to push, use:

```
 MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => MainGameScreen.create(context),
    ),
```

And with this solution, we had a Provider above the `MainGameScreen` ;). And remember this is very hard to add widget test so think twice before using it.

Sorry for my previous stupid explanation!

Answer (score 2):

I think that inside the MainGameScreen, you used some code like:
`final bloc = Provider.of<AuthBloc>(context, listen: false,);`.

When this is called, the provider package will use the `context` of the MainGameScreen and find whether there is a `Provider` Widget with a type of `AuthBloc` above it. If the package can't find it, that exception will be thrown.

```
The following ProviderNotFoundException was thrown building Builder:
Error: Could not find the correct Provider<AuthBloc> above this MainGameScreen Widget
```

So i think you should add a `Provider` with a type of `AuthBloc` above the `MainGameScreen` Widget, it often look like this:

```
Provider<AuthBloc>(
create: (context) => AuthBloc(),
dispose: (context, bloc) => bloc.dispose(), // remove it if there is no dispose method in your BLoC
child: MainGameScreen(),
),
```

You can add this `Provider` everywhere above the `MainGameScreen()` and it also has to have a type of `AuthBloc` (`Provider<AuthBloc>`).

Comment: @Tran yes I have listen: false inside MainGameScreen(). But I didn't understand where to place this Provider<AuthBloc>. MainGameScreen is a stateful widget. If I place it outside the widget it gives error.